# cursor in forms 6i

Tags: sql, oracle, oracleforms

I am working on Forms 6i. I want to use a `case` expression in a cursor. But the code does not compile.

Does Forms 6i not support the case expression in cursor? Is there any other method to write case expression in Forms?

Answer (score 3):

In almost all cases I can think of, you can use nested `decode`s instead of `case`.

Instead of

```
 select case when a=1 then 'foo'
             when b>2 then 'bar'
             else 'foobar' end
   from xyz;
```

you can write

```
 select decode(a,1,        'foo',
        decode(sign(b-2),1,'bar',
                           'foobar')) from xyz;
```

The other, probably more elegant possibility, is to create a database view and use it in forms, so forms 6i never sees the `case`.

Comment: +1 I should have included a solution like yours in my response rather than just explaining why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the pl/sql engine used in Forms 6i is "old" and wasn't aware of `CASE` statements when it was developed. (As I recall, server side pl/sql only introduced `CASE` statements at Oracle 9i)

I don't have a copy of form builder 9i so can't comment on that version but `CASE` statements are available in Forms 10g and above.

Comment: CASE was available in Oracle 8i, but not (directly) in PL/SQL programs. But Forms PL/SQL lagged (significantly) behind the server PL/SQL. I *think* it was only 10gR2 Forms that could manage CASE.